# How to add custom labels to contentView of a UITableViewCell in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, interface-builder

I'm loading a custom UITableViewCell from a CatsTableViewCell.xib file. It contains a custom label which I added in Interface Builder. The cell is visible in the table view. All looks fine.

But when I click the cell in the simulator, the whole cell turns blue. I was not able to hook up the label to contentView and have been told by others that Interface Builder adds subviews of cells automatically to contentView.

Can someone tell me what is going on, why the selection state covers the label? I think this should not happen if it was the contentView.

All I did was create a custom backgroundView that draws a gradient, and add a label there. Interface Builder keeps adding my label as child to the background view which is awkward. I can't position it in the root either as the cell must be the only root object. And IB won't let me put the label above the background view either. When I do that I cannot position the label and every time I click it, IB will add it as child to the background view.

[image]

[image]

This is how it looks when I drag the label above the backgroundView. It disappears behind it. Clicking the label and trying to position it will make it a child of backgroundView again:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In IB when an object is above another in the list view it's actually 'below' it. The list view shows the hierarchy from 'bottom to top', so to speak.

Your hierarchy should look like this:

[image]

You may find it difficult to drag the label below your background - as you've found out, if you're not pixel perfect XCode will make it a child of the background view, which you don't want. The solution here is to drag the background view above the label instead. Hope this helps you out!